# postgresql select max no if date is same

Tags: postgresql

i have a table like:

```
  sr_no    or_no     date
  1        1         2017-01-01  
  1        2         2017-02-02
  1        3         2017-02-02
  2        1         2017-01-02
  2        2         2017-01-10
```

What i want is if date field for a sr_no is same then record with max or_no should be fetched. Output should be like:

```
sr_no     or_no    date
1         1        2017-01-01
1         3        2017-02-02
2         1        2017-01-02
2         2        2017-01-10
```

Comment: `select distinct on ("date") * from t order by d,or_no desc;`

Answer (score 0):

just distinct on to cut max(or_no) with order:

```
with a as (select distinct on (d) * from t order by d,or_no desc)
select * from a order by sr_no,or_no;
 sr_no | or_no |     d
-------+-------+------------
     1 |     1 | 2017-01-01
     1 |     3 | 2017-02-02
     2 |     1 | 2017-01-02
     2 |     2 | 2017-01-10
(4 rows)
```

Comment: sorry, i am new to this, what is t=# in your answer. Can you please write the whole query once again. It's a request.

Comment: ok i got it  **select * from (select distinct on (d) * from t order by d,or_no desc) as a order by sr_no,or_no**

Comment: acually i was confuesd in "with a as"